# CBPeripheral setNotifyValue WithResponse do not call didWriteValueForCharacteristic

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE fund to write data to a Peripheral service:

```
func writeData(data: [Int8]) {
    let character = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: cuivienenCharacterUUID, properties: [.Write, .Read, .Notify], value: nil, permissions: [.Readable, .Writeable])
    test_peripheral.writeValue(NSData(bytes: data, length: data.count), forCharacteristic: character, type: .WithResponse)
    test_peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: character)
}
```

I have already init test_peripheral and set its delegate to self. But `test_peripheral.writeValue` never called `func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)`. I can't receive even a error message!

So does `test_peripheral.setNotifyValue`. It never invokes `func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?)`

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

CBCharacteristic in

```
test_peripheral.writeValue(NSData(bytes: data, length: data.count), forCharacteristic: character, type: .WithResponse)
```

should not be init by your own code. You should find your CBCharacteristic in

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?)
```

and then use it.